# How to invoke C# method from PowerShell whose signature has parameters marked with 'params'

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to invoke a C# library method from PowerShell that has the following signature:

```
public void Load<T>(T thing, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals);
```

For the 'retrievals' parameter, I only want to pass just one Expression argument, but when I do, PowerShell gives me the following error:

> Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "2".

I'm trying to use this:

```
$context.Load($thing, @($expressionTree1))
```

It keeps throwing that error.

I'm using PowerShell 5 and the C# library is the client side object model for SharePoint 2016.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second parameter must be an array of `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be shortest solution in your case.

```
$code = 
@'
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public void Load<T>(T thing, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] retrievals)
        {
            foreach (var retrieval in retrievals)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Retrieval: " + retrieval);
            }
        }

        private static Expression<Func<T, object>> FuncToExpression<T>(Func<T, object> f)  
        {  
            return x => f(x);  
        } 

        public void Load2<T>(T thing, params Func<T, object>[] retrievals)
        {
            var funcs = new Expression<Func<T, object>>[retrievals.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < retrievals.Length; i++)
            {
                funcs[i] = FuncToExpression(retrievals[i]);
            }

            this.Load<T>(thing, funcs);
        }

        public void Test1()
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            this.Load<Entity>(entity, e => e.Property1, e => e.Property2);
        }
    }
'@
```

There is helper method `Load2` but you can easly rewrite it to PowerShell. The key is another helper method `FuncToExpression`. It's possible to compile Linq expression "by hand" but it's much more complicated.

Sample of use:

```
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
    $o = New-Object TestClass
    $o.Test1()
    $entity = New-Object Entity
    $func1 = [Func`2[Entity, object]]{ param($e) $e.Property1 }
    $func2 = [Func`2[Entity, object]]{ param($e) $e.Property2 }
    $o.Load2($entity, [Func`2[Entity, object][]]@($func, $func2))
```

Comment: This worked. Though I wish there was a more PowerShell'y way of doing it.